# building androidTest apk gets R8 errors: "already has a mapping"

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

I have added `minifyEnabled=true` to my 'release' build.  The app runs correctly.  And the androidTest apk runs correctly (all tests pass).

If I add *any* of the following to proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keepattributes LineNumberTable
-keepattributes LocalVariableTable
-keepattributes LocalVariableTypeTable
```

the app apk will build without error, but while building the androidTest apk I get ~4000 R8 "already has a mapping" errors for task:

```
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForReleaseAndroidTest
```

The (truncated) error log is

[image: androidTest build error: already has a mapping]

It appears that the methods that are getting the error are in 3rd party libraries (included as dependencies).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding an additional buildType for testing the 'release' configuration ('releaseTest').  It inherits from 'release', and sets `debuggable=true`.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
    }
    release {
        ...
        minifyEnabled true    // enable code shrinking & obfuscation
        shrinkResources true  // enable resource shrinking
        ...
    }
    releaseTest {
        // inherit from 'release' buildType
        initWith release
        // for dependencies that don't know what 'releaseTest' is
        matchingFallbacks = ['release']

        debuggable true
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and adding

```
-dontoptimize
```

into my `proguard-rules.pro` just works for me.

Comment: This isn't an answer, you're just disabling optimizations entirely and avoiding solving the actual issue